# Asset pricing Coursera resources

Tags: reference-request, asset-pricing

I am trying to learn [John Cochrane's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_H._Cochrane) *[Asset Pricing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_H._Cochrane#Asset_Pricing)*. I notice there are [Coursera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coursera) resources ([link](https://www.coursera.org/instructor/johncochrane)). However, it is not available now. Did anyone try that class before? Does anyone know what's the next time it opens? Is it worth waiting for? Are there any good alternatives?

Comment: That particular course closed down on July 1 or so. I downloaded the videos for it because I don't think there's any plans to reopen the course, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Is it possible that you share the videos? Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have uploaded all the videos on YouTube as two separate playlists which cover asset pricing part 1 & 2 courses.

Asset Pricing part 1:  https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLpccx1MwQZb7t7HJ6lBo4L3DXhknCD0K7&disable_polymer=true

Asset Pricing part 2:  https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLpccx1MwQZb6XsKU3O81GrpqaxyyGoHpH

Regarding the class, I think Coursera moved to the new platform and thats why these courses and some others have disappeared. I heard that they are preparing the courses based on the new platform.

Answer (score 2):

Cochrane has made the material from his Coursera course available online on his [personal website](http://faculty.chicagobooth.edu/john.cochrane/teaching/asset_pricing.htm). This includes all of the video lectures (both [part 1](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLAXSVuGaw0KxTEN_cy-RCuEzzRdnF_xtx) and [part 2](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLAXSVuGaw0KxVUym8IRkObSbUPEFaSbPt)). 
John notes that "it should be open and free to anyone, including all the quizzes, problem sets and exams."

You can read a [post about it on his blog](https://johnhcochrane.blogspot.com/2016/08/asset-pricing-mooc-resurrected.html).